# Outlook shows error about the data file not being closed properly

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Whenever I open Outlook I get the following message:

> The data file was not closed properly. This file is being checked for problems.

… and suddenly many spam mails arrive in my mailbox.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: Is this an OST or PST?  If it is a pst you might try repairing it.

Comment: i tried to repair it.its not working. then i got more than thousands spam mail

Answer (score 0):

I would do export of all personal folders (incl. subfolders) to new .pst file.

```
File -> Open -> Import -> and select "export to file"
```

Then not import, but add exported.pst file to outlook as second one, set it as default, set it as default for your account and then remove the original one.

```
File -> Info -> Account Settings
In "Account Settings" go to tab "Data Settings" and "Add" exported.pst
Set it as default
On tab E-mail, then select Inbox for your Account from exported.pst
```

Answer (score 0):

This message appears if last time outlook not closed properly, kindly complete the scan and reopen outlook. It should resolve your problem, other wise Scan PST is good free tool to repair PST file.

Comment: same problem occured daily and many repeated mails coming.can i reinstall my OS .it be ll clear?